# Bernstein polynomial: function to approximate

Tags: polynomials, approximation, interpolation

I am studying the Bernstein polynomial with Matlab. I wish to code the example in the wikipedia page of [Bernstein polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial), but I can not figure out the explicit form of the red function (see figure).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is impossible figure out the explicit formula of the red function using only a picture of its graph. However, [this](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bernstein_Approximation.gif) description says:

> This animation was created with Maple 9.5 and Jasc Animation Shop. It shows Bernstein polynomials approximating $x \sin(\frac 72\pi {\sqrt {x}})$ (chosen for purely aesthetic reasons).

Although, it appears that the true formula is $-x \sin(\frac 72\pi {\sqrt {x}})$.